# How to search particular file in command prompt by using file name instead?

Tags: windows, command-line, file-management

How to search a particular file in the command prompt by using its name.

for eg:

```
C:\>dir examplefile.txt /s /d
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 5200-9295
```

its shows this only. help me out to search a particular file in particular dir on drive.

Comment: Leave it running, until it returns to `c:\>`. If it just shows the volume label, it's searching...

Comment: Yeah...but given command is correct? Can i give filename after dir?

Comment: Yes, of course. That's exactly how `dir` works. I usually prefer to do `dir /s filename` but it doesn't matter if you put the switches at the end.